# Variable length args in macro in Visual C++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

After years of mostly using gcc, I suddenly have a need to use Visual C++ on Windows. The latest thing I need to translate is this:

```cpp
#ifdef DBG_ENABLE
#define DBG_PRINT(x...)  printf(x)
#else
#define DBG_PRINT(x...)
#endif
```

Which gives me this error:

```
error C2010: '.': unexpected in macro parameter list
```

Can someone please share the Windows way of doing this?

I tried googling and searching the Microsoft docs, but couldn't figure out a way to phrase the question that brought relevant results.

Comment: C supports variadic macros, C++ does not.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Maybe, but Microsoft's [C++ compiler does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/variadic-macros).

Comment: This appears to be using a non-standard GCC-specific extension, and it's not clear what the effect should be. Please explain what the function-like macro should expand to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define DBG_PRINT(x...)  printf(x)` is not the correct syntax for using variadic macros in VC++.

Per Microsoft documentation on [Variadic macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/variadic-macros), try this instead:

```
#ifdef DBG_ENABLE
#define DBG_PRINT(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DBG_PRINT(...)
#endif
```

Or:

```
#ifdef DBG_ENABLE
#define DBG_PRINT(s, ...) printf(s, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DBG_PRINT(s, ...)
#endif
```

Comment: So far I'm just compiling as regular C, not C++ (.c files and no /Tp or /TP options to cl.exe).

Comment: For the DBG_ENABLE defined case: `#define DBG_PRINT(...)  printf(__VA_ARGS__)` works (thanks @Remy), `#define DBG_PRINT(x, ...)  printf(x)` doesn't work.  For the DBG_ENABLE not defined case: `#define DBG_PRINT(...)` doesn't work, `#define DBG_PRINT(x, ...)` works.

Comment: @she As I pointed out in a comment to your question, the code is using non-standard syntax. Please explain what *"works"* and *"doesn't work"* means to you.

Comment: @IInspectable You replace the word "printf" with the word "DBG_PRINT" throughout your code.  When you define DBG_ENABLE, you see the prints.  When you don't define it, no prints.  That and no compiler warnings in either case is how I define "works".

Comment: @she Again, what should the macros **expand** to. Like, in full. Not just the part that's easy to guess. You're using a non-standard compiler-specific language extension. Don't expect others to be intimately familiar with non-standard behavior. And make sure to add that information to your question.

Comment: @IInspectable I've never actually looked at a listing of the pre-processor output, but I assumed it just replaced with DBG_PRINT with printf (left the arguments untouched) in the defined case, and removed the lines altogether in the not defined case.  Also, the solution provided by Remy is working for me, so no need to pursue this any further.  Thanks though.